# Add cursor none for the whole page onclick even for buttons with cursor Styling (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a button with a cursor and what I wanted was that when you click on the button that **EVERYTHING** gets a `cursor: none;`. If you click on the button then the cursor for the body goes away but if you hover on a button or an element with a cursor then the cursor is back. How could I fix this problem? And how can i improve my code?

Here is my code:

```js
function removeCursor() {
  document.getElementById("body").style.cursor = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <button onclick="removeCursor();" id="button">Hello</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I fix this problem? And how can i improve my code?

The correct answer (IMHO) to both of those is: Do. Not. Set. Inline. Styles.

Add a class to the body element instead.

Then you can easily format not only body, but also all of its descendants, via one rule in your stylesheet.

```js
function removeCursor() {
  document.body.className = "unusable";
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body.unusable,
body.unusable * {
  cursor: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <button onclick="removeCursor();" id="button">Hello</button>
</body>
```

`body.unusable *` creates enough specificity here to overwrite the `button` selector; in cases that are a bit more complex, this would be one of the instances where it would also be justifiable to add `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

You could it this way :

```js
function removeCursor() {
  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(element => element.style.cursor = 'none');
}
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="removeCursor();" id="button">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById("body").style.cursor = "none";

This means that the cursor of the body element style has changed none.

If you want change every element in Body, first you get all element in body

I hope this code helping you

```
function removeCursor() {
   document.body.getElementsByTagName("*").forEach(ele=>ele.style.cursor = 'none');
}
```